# Android: OnClickListener in RecyclerView items behaves different in emulator and on real device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm quite new to Android developing - and quite stunned:

I have an Activity showing a RecyclerView with CardViews added to it.

Each CardView has a View.OnClickListener attached and each CardView also contains an ImageView which has a View.OnLongClickListener attached.
Furthermore the RecyclerView has a RecyclerView.ItemTouchHelper attached to support Drag (by dragging the whole CardView) and Swipe (by swiping the ImageView inside the CardView, so the ImageView serves as a kind of a Handle).

So far, all these Listeners as well as the Dragging and Swiping work perfectly in harmony on the emulator (any emulated Android version) inside Android Studio (using mouse clicks). But when it comes to a real (Lollipop) device (using touches), the OnClickListener in the CardView does not seem to work anymore. It shows the visual effect of clicking the item, but the onClick method is not called - like the clicking/touching event is not being recognized or another "hidden" Listener catches and consumes it.

Would be easy to troubleshoot, if the behaviour was the same on Emulator and real device. But as it's not, I must assume, the behaviour could be different on any (real) device?

Didn't find any useful reference that app **behaviour** would be different between emulator and real device, but only that the app might not even start on a real device when running smoothly in the emulator... any ideas?

**This is the implementation of my Listeners:**

```
private class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final Context context;

    public MyOnClickListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("ClickListener", "onClick fired");
        int selectedItemPosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
        Flight f = flightListRecyclerAdapter.getFlight(selectedItemPosition);
        if (data().getNewFlights().contains(f)) {
            data().getNewFlights().remove(f);
            flightListRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemChanged(selectedItemPosition);
        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ShowFlightsActivity.this, EditFlightActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EditFlightActivity.FLIGHT_INFO, f);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    }


}

private class MyOnLongClickListener implements View.OnLongClickListener {

    private final Context context;

    public MyOnLongClickListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Log.i("ClickListener", "onLongClick fired");
        int selectedItemPosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition((View) v.getParent().getParent());
        Flight f = flightListRecyclerAdapter.getFlight(selectedItemPosition);
        FlightListViewHolder viewHolder = (FlightListViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(selectedItemPosition);

        // toggle assumption of flight (but only for foreign flights)
        synchronized (LocalData.getInstance().getLock()) {
            if (f.getAssumptions() != null) {
                if (f.getAssumptions().size() == 0 || !f.getAssumptions().get(0).getAirport().equals(data().getOwnAirport())) {
                    assumeFlight(f);
                } else {
                    unassumeFlight(f);
                }
            }
            setCardBackground(ShowFlightsActivity.this, viewHolder.getCardView(), f);
        }


        return true;
    }
}
```

**The TouchHelperCallback:**

```
public class FlightListItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

private final FlightListItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter;

public FlightListItemTouchHelperCallback(FlightListItemTouchHelperAdapter adapter) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    // support up and down movement
    int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
    int swipeFlags=0;
    if (viewHolder instanceof FlightListViewHolder) {
        FlightListViewHolder flightListViewHolder = (FlightListViewHolder) viewHolder;
        if (flightListViewHolder.dismissable) {
            swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
        }
    }
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    adapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

    adapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

}

@Override
public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

**Static method called from within the Adapter in the onCreateViewHolder() (I extracted this to use the same functionality at another place - different activity, so should not be the problem, I think), here the Listeners are attached to the CardViews:**

```
public static FlightListViewHolder createViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, Context context, boolean setListeners) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.flightlist_layout, parent, false);
    FlightListViewHolder flightListViewHolder = new FlightListViewHolder(view);
    ImageView leftImage = flightListViewHolder.leftImage;
    ImageView rightImage = flightListViewHolder.rightImage;
    if (setListeners) {
        view.setOnClickListener(ShowFlightsActivity.getMyOnClickListener());
        leftImage.setOnLongClickListener(ShowFlightsActivity.getMyOnLongClickListener());
        rightImage.setOnLongClickListener(ShowFlightsActivity.getMyOnLongClickListener());
    }

    return flightListViewHolder;
}
```

EDIT: I think I see the problem now... I'm also setting an OnTouchListener on the same cardView... But I'm still wondering how this worked inside the Emulator ....

EDIT2: Indeed the problem raised because of having both the OnTouchListener and the OnClickListener. I finally solved it by overriding View.OnTouchEvent in my CardView to give a performClick() if the touch event turned out to be a click (after this the OnClickListener is properly working):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(e) ==
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.i("ClickableCardView", "onTouch fired");
        impactPoint = e.getX();
    } else if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(e) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (impactPoint - e.getX() == 0) {
            Log.i("ClickableCardView", "this was a click");
            performClick();
        } else {
            Log.i("ClickableCardView", "this was a move: " + Float.toString(impactPoint - e.getX()));
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: We need to see some code in order to help you.

Comment: sorry, hat troubles, now the code is added :)

Comment: Not sure what your listeners really do (so it may not matter technically) but I'd not set them in `createViewHolder()` but in `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: I just see now in LogCat that every time I click on the card view, the following Message appears: "D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN" (on the real device) and "W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=513.43506, y[0]=1253.6133, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=72366, downTime=70609, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }" on emulator...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski ok I did that, but it did not help. Still getting "D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN" instead of "onClick fired".